# Online translation web applications

Tags: translation, google-translate

Which online translation web applications are most popular (something like [Google translate](http://translate.google.com/#))?

Comment: looks like this results in a list so this should be community wiki.

Comment: It's also subjective.

Comment: Agree with both :D

Comment: What the hell, instead of providing answers you try to critic questions, men. This is a beta stackexchange site and we need to stimulate users to be active, I think.

Comment: and because it's in beta we kinda have to do that to make it "right".. do you agree with the first two comments or not?

Comment: and don't forget that you'll get much better answers if you change it to CW..

Comment: question needs to be a lot more detailed, more than just "what is popular". Popular.. by whose metrics? Popular.. by what criteria?

Answer (score 2):

## Google Translate

[Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/) - Simply because is the best and the most popular.

Comment: This will end up in a list.. and this shouldn't be out of the list..

Comment: But I said EXCEPT google translate.

Comment: @Bakhtiyor.. I know.. ;) but let's just put all of them in the same list..

Comment: @Bakhtiyor and then the next question is "online translation tools except google translate AND [insert winner of this list here]"...

Answer (score 2):

You will find lots of translator links from this page

http://www.skatelog.com/translate.htm

Comment: This question is a poll and I think everything should be included in order to vote for the best one.. something like http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2050/what-is-your-most-used-web-application it would be hard to exclude the most obvious one..

Comment: and it would be nice to take few from this list and add them as separate answers here.

Answer (score 2):

## Yahoo! Babel Fish

[Yahoo! Babel Fish](http://babelfish.yahoo.com/) because it's classic and old school.

Answer (score 0):

### MyMemory

http://mymemory.translated.net/

This has been my favourite lately.